# Compact image picker from iMessage app

Tags: ios, uikit, imessage

iOS 10 has new compact image picker. Is there anything like that in iMessage App SDK? Or it is limited to Apple apps only?

Comment: what do you mean by compact image picker? can you share link or any reference?

Comment: the one which is default now in iMessage